# skip/ignore field magento 2 csv import

Tags: magento2.3, import

For an import file that has some records with new data for category column and others that don't need updating. Is there a skip/ignore field word I can put into those fields like magmi's "MAGMI_IGNORE" ?

Comment: Simple thing is only add fields which you want to update in csv don't add fields which you do not want to update.

Comment: Thank you, my files are mixed so I need an easy way to use those files without separating files